# TypeScript caching static object imported from file

Tags: javascript, typescript, caching

The weirdest thing just occured to me. But caching issues are always scary...

- In 1) I'm assigning defaultConfig to the variable `config`
- In 2) you can see, that `defaultConfig` is imported from a file. That is the file in 3)
- You see that the file in 3) contains a static object.
- However, in 4) you see what the debugger shows. The app is having all kinds of items in that object. Those items are from the previous run.

So, to explain. On the first run, all is fine. But once you merged fields into the `config` what happens on the next run of that script is, that config holds all those fields **initially**.

What is causing that? And more importantly, how to end that mess?

[image]

Comment: You're modifying your config instance (which comes from module) in your post method. You need to clone your default config instead of using it directly.

Comment: Thanks @SalientBrain, because in JS every assignment is a reference? Is that the underlying cause?

Comment: Indeed, `const config: PostRequestBodyType = { ...defaultConfig };` fixed it.